# Azure function to read file from azure devops repository

Tags: c#, .net, azure, file

I am looking for a way how my azure function can read a files from an azure (devops) repository. The file content is to be used in a RESTfull Post or Put request afterwards. The files in the repository are updated from time to time.

The process will be triggered manually from a web-page triggering the azure function.

How would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, I think you're looking to update the file in Azure repo.
Please go through below documentation from MSDN to get more insights on Azure repo API.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0

Below code sample is from Microsoft Github repo [here](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-dotnet-samples/blob/master/ClientLibrary/Samples/Git/ItemsSample.cs).

```
namespace Microsoft.Azure.DevOps.ClientSamples.Git
{
    [ClientSample(GitWebApiConstants.AreaName, "items")]
    public class ItemsSample : ClientSample
    {
        [ClientSampleMethod]
        public IEnumerable<GitItem> ListItems()
        {
        VssConnection connection = this.Context.Connection;
        GitHttpClient gitClient = connection.GetClient<GitHttpClient>();

        TeamProjectReference project = ClientSampleHelpers.FindAnyProject(this.Context);
        GitRepository repo = GitSampleHelpers.FindAnyRepository(this.Context, project.Id);

        List<GitItem> items = gitClient.GetItemsAsync(repo.Id, scopePath: "/", recursionLevel: VersionControlRecursionType.OneLevel).Result;

        Console.WriteLine("project {0}, repo {1}", project.Name, repo.Name);
        foreach(GitItem item in items)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", item.GitObjectType, item.ObjectId, item.Path);
        }

        return items;            
    }

    [ClientSampleMethod]
    public GitItem GetItem()
    {
        VssConnection connection = this.Context.Connection;
        GitHttpClient gitClient = connection.GetClient<GitHttpClient>();

        TeamProjectReference project = ClientSampleHelpers.FindAnyProject(this.Context);
        GitRepository repo = GitSampleHelpers.FindAnyRepository(this.Context, project.Id);

        // get a filename we know exists
        string filename = gitClient.GetItemsAsync(repo.Id, scopePath: "/", recursionLevel: VersionControlRecursionType.OneLevel).Result
            .Where(o => o.GitObjectType == GitObjectType.Blob).FirstOrDefault().Path;

        // retrieve the contents of the file
        GitItem item = gitClient.GetItemAsync(repo.Id, filename, includeContent: true).Result;

        Console.WriteLine("File {0} at commit {1} is of length {2}", filename, item.CommitId, item.Content.Length);

        return item;
    }
}
}
```